# Copy folders /home /usr and /opt from hd2

Tags: ssd

I have the following partitions on my machine:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="0c910853-807a-4c08-9257-ff028ec31287" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="000bb0e6-01" 
/dev/sdb1: UUID="8ca21db1-81b0-42d0-8f56-fde9031c7d70" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="000d3067-01" 
/dev/sdb5: UUID="d5e91016-6e23-4664-a460-4e6368ee3e8c" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="000d3067-05"
```

I want to move:  /home /usr and /opt from sda1
I've tried the command:

```
 sudo mount /dev/sdb1/ /mnt/tmp
    mount: special device /dev/sdb1/ does not exist (a path prefix is not a directory)
```

But I can not mount the folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/tmp
```

`/dev/sdb1` is not a directory - a trailing slash shouldn't be present.

Comment: tks, worked for /home now necessary to create new partitions for the /opt?